# JVM Option MaxMetaspaceSize - What is Optimal value to set?

Tags: jvm

I have application, have set around 8GB of Max heap memory, it does lots of message processing. when I am taking jmap -heap for my application, it shows me very huge MaxMetaspaceSize memory, something like below,

MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB

If I have to put the limit on MaxMetaspaceSize, what could be optimal value for that?

Note* - I have read on pros and cons of putting limit of MaxMetaspaceSize

Comment: If you don't know what value to set, why you do want to set it in the first place?

Comment: Basically, to control the native memory used by Java Process. I have 3 such processes running on 32GB physical memory box and task manager shows around 10GB for each process, thereby I am trying to limit the native memory allocation. I am using NMT JDK utility.

Comment: If you are using NMT, then you already know how much Metaspace your application uses. Setting `MaxMetaspaceSize` won't make application use less - instead it can make application crash with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: The “very huge MaxMetaspaceSize ” just tells you that there is no limit for the meta space. It doesn’t say anything about how much has been actually allocated or used.

Answer (score 0):

Measure how much metaspace your program needs once it has settled into a steady state. Add some safety margin, then configure that as your max.

Should your program change behavior, e.g. load additional classes without unloading old ones you'll be notified about that through OOMEs.

> it shows me very huge MaxMetaspaceSize memory

Note that that is just the upper limit enforced by the JVM, not the actual size.